# Don't order by attribute

Tags: c#, linq

I have DB, consists of 2 tables:

```
**Job**
     job_id (int, primary key),
     job_nm (nchar(50))

**Employee**
     empl_id (int, primary key)
     job_id (int, forein key) (one-to-many)
     first_name (nchar(50))
     last_name (nchar(50))
     salary (float)
```

I output the table by pages (5 rows by page).
It realize:

```
ViewBag.Tab = (from employee in db.Employees 
               join job in db.Jobs on employee.job_id equals job.job_id 
               where job.job_nm == sel1 
               orderby employee.salary 
               select employee
              ).Skip(pageSize * pageNum)
               .Take(pageSize)
               .ToList();
```

But I have unsorted by "salary"-field list.

I tried this code:

```
ViewBag.Tab = (from employee in db.Employees 
               join job in db.Jobs 
               on employee.job_id equals job.job_id 
               where job.job_nm == sel1 
               orderby employee.salary 
               select employee
              ).Skip(pageSize * pageNum)
               .Take(pageSize)
               .ToList()
               .OrderBy(s => s.salary);
```

but it haven't result.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The `OrderBy` needs to come before the `Skip` and `Take`. Other wise you are just going to order your small result set.

Try:

```
ViewBag.Tab = (from employee in db.Employees 
               join job in db.Jobs 
               on employee.job_id equals job.job_id 
               where job.job_nm == sel1 
               orderby employee.salary 
               select employee
              ).OrderBy(s => s.salary)
               .Skip(pageSize * pageNum)
               .Take(pageSize)
               .ToList();
```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't sort result by "salary":(

Comment: I notice that you already have an order by in your query, if you take out the OrderBy in the LINQ statement, does that help?